# Issue when trying to represent an operator as a matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

We say that a ket $|V\rangle$ can be expresed in an orthonormal basis $(|e_1\rangle,|e_2\rangle,...|e_n\rangle)$ as :
$$|V\rangle = \sum_i^n v_i |e_i\rangle$$

where $v_i = \langle i|V\rangle $

for a linear operator $\hat A$:

$$|V'\rangle = \hat A |V\rangle$$

if we want to express $|V'\rangle$ in terms of $v_j'$ we can say that $v_j' = \langle j|V'\rangle $

where $$|V'\rangle = \sum_j^n v_j' |e_j\rangle$$

thus $$v_j' =  \sum_i^n v_i \langle e_j|\hat A|e_i\rangle $$

and $$A_{ji} = \langle e_j|\hat A|e_i\rangle $$

but if I had expressed $|V'\rangle$ using the same dummy index as I did for $|V\rangle$ we would get that

$$A_{?i} = \langle e_i|\hat A|e_i\rangle $$

and now I do not have a second index to describe the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, why would a dummy index matter this much and why is it wrong to use the same dummy index?

Comment: Beside the point, but is it not true that $A_{ii} = \langle e_i | \hat{A} | e_i \rangle$?

Comment: The reason it matters so much is that a dummy index like used here stands for something that you are summing over. If you are combining two different sums in one expression, you are fooling yourself if you think the two sums can be combined into a single sum without thinking about it. It is as foolish as using the variable $x$ for multiple different things when solving simultaneous equations.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer why is $A_{ii} \not = \langle e_i|\hat A | e_i \rangle$ ? if $j ==i$ shouldn't it be true?

Comment: Yes it is true, so I was wondering why you brought it up as a point in your post.

Comment: Your question is aggressively opaque. Have you tried an obvious *n* =2 example with a simple matrix?